# Google sign-in not refreshing page

Tags: javascript, google-signin

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Ive looked on Google forums but can't find any topic specifically for sign-ins.

I'm adding Google sign-in. The log-out works fine, it auto-refreshes the page when i click the log-out URL, thus making the cookie disappear.

However - when I LOG IN, the "icon" / "button on Google says Google is signed-in, however my page hasn't refreshed & still doesn't see the cookie value..  (my main language is PHP). The button itself doesn't activate a java-script to refresh the entire page.

If i MANUALLY refresh the page, it does recognize the logged-in cookie.

Does anyone have a full working example - Not just snippets of code, that will  log me in to google but also refresh the page itself.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

http://foe.kwister.com/members/

what i'll like is to go to a URL http://foe.kwister.com/members/?switch=2 when the person logs in. this will refresh the page. (THOUGH i dont want it to go to that URL if i'm already logged in, and cause an endless refresh loop.)

is this possible ?

EDIT: (25 Feb 2020) - Ive altered my code - re-typed it all again exactly how the tutorial advises, but its not even signing out at all - its permanently signed in.

The video suggests / refers to a code example, but i cant find any. Has anyone got a working test page with the bare minumum code to make a working example.

Comment: I can see that `onSignIn(googleUser)` is firing. So, add the redirect code on at the bottom

Comment: Is the sign-out part right ? I can sign in, bit its not letting me sign out